# AS3 ios cameraUI save and load image fails, why?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the AS3 code below to take a photo throught the cameraUI. Everything works fine on the Android but when I test on the iPad I get an error when trying to load the saved image. The ioErrorHandler1 returns:

ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type. URL: app-storage:/myImage.jpg" errorID=2124]

Anyone know why? (as mentioned it works on Android). Here's the code:

```
      function imageCaptured( event:MediaEvent ):void
      {
           trace( "Media captured..." );
            var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;
           dataSource = imagePromise.open();    
           if( imagePromise.isAsync )
           {
            trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );

            eventSource = dataSource as IEventDispatcher; 
            imageLoader = new Loader();
            imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, asyncImageLoaded );
            imageLoader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cameraError );

                 imageLoader.loadFilePromise( imagePromise );
           }
           else
           {
            trace( "Synchronous media promise." );
            imageLoader.loadFilePromise( imagePromise );
            showMedia( imageLoader );
           }
      }
    function asyncImageLoaded( event:Event ):void
      {

            readMediaData();

      }
    function readMediaData():void
    {

var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageLoader.content);
var bitmap:BitmapData = image.bitmapData;

image.width = 100;
image.height = 100;
this.addChild(image);

var imageBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
dataSource.readBytes( imageBytes );

var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myImage.jpg");
// create a file stream
var fs:FileStream=new FileStream();
// open the stream for writting
fs.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
// write the string data down to the file
fs.writeBytes(imageBytes);
// ok close the file stream
fs.close();

fs.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE,function(event:Event):void {
    var mLoader=new Loader();
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file.url);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void{
                                showMediaLoad(mLoader);
                        });
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler1);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);

    mLoader.load(mRequest);

})

trace("saved");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to encode your ByteArray before saving it as a jpeg.

Here's a snippet of code I used a while back...

```
import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;

private var f:File;
private var stream:FileStream;
private var j:JPGEncoder;
private var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(imageLoader.content);
private var urlRequest:URLRequest;
private var loader:Loader;

function saveImage():void {

f = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("logo.jpg"); 

stream = new FileStream();
stream.open(f, FileMode.WRITE);                                         

j = new JPGEncoder(80);
var bytes:ByteArray = j.encode(image.bitmapData);
stream.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.bytesAvailable);
stream.close();

stream.openAsync(f, FileMode.READ); 
stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImage, false, 0, true); 
}



private function loadImage(e:Event):void {

stream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadImage);
stream = null;

//now load the image

if (f.exists == true) {

urlRequest = new URLRequest(f.url);
loader = new Loader;
loader.load(urlRequest);
loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(e:IOErrorEvent):void{ trace(e) });
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoaded, false, 0, true);

}
}

private function ImageLoaded(e:Event):void {

addChild(loader);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoaded);
}
```

Comment: Yes it works when using the jpg encoder, thanks! The only issue is that  it's very slow. The save part take a long time. Do you know why? I think it's strange that my code doesn't work on the iPad when it works on the Android.

Comment: I imagine it's the encoding that is taking the time, not the actual saving. Perhaps look for a more efficient encoding method?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It works without jpgencoder if I put an eventlistener on the eventSource. I'm posting it here if anyone else could use the solution:

The imageCaptured function is updated like this:

```
     if( imagePromise.isAsync )
           {
            trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );
            var eventSource:IEventDispatcher = dataSource as IEventDispatcher;
    eventSource.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onMediaLoaded );


           }
```

And then the image is save in this function:

```
function onMediaLoaded( event:Event ):void
{
trace("Media load complete");

var imageBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
dataSource.readBytes( imageBytes );

var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("myImage.jpg");
// create a file stream
var fs:FileStream=new FileStream();
// open the stream for writting
fs.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
// write the string data down to the file
//fs.writeBytes(imageBytes);
fs.writeBytes(imageBytes);

// ok close the file stream
fs.close();

fs.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, function(e:Event):void {

    var mLoader=new Loader();
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file.url);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (event:Event):void{
  showMediaLoad(mLoader);

 });
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler1);
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);

mLoader.load(mRequest);
}
```